# Managed Metadata 403 Error on Contributor Edit

Tags: managed-metadata, 403

1. I log into portal using spadmin account, then go to a doc lib "TestDocLib". I can see the values for all the metadata fields (about 8 metadata fields) and I can click on Edit to open the editform.aspx (and perform modification if needed).
2. I added user in a spgroup with contribute access. The user jsmith logs in, go to TestDocLib, the entity column in the view shows up but values are nulled or empty and he gets 403b error when clicking on the edit button. (however, view properties and then edit item lets him modify the data).

What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion fixed both the managed metadata type columns values are not displayed and the 403 errors.

http://sharepoint-talk.blogspot.com/2011/07/metadata-column-not-visible-for-users.html

Thank you Amol

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that this is a permissions issue. Please see this post for how to fix:

**Users Cannot See Managed Metadata Column Values in SharePoint 2010**
http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Users-Cannot-See-Managed-Metadata-Column-Values-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx